# Does C# treat types which don't allow null from F# still nullable?

Tags: f#

It is interop between C# and F#

In F#,

```
type test =
{
    value: int
}

type Wrapper (value: test) =
    member val Value = value with get, set

let trythis = new Wrapper(null)  // error as expected
```

However, in C#

```
 var trythis = new Wrapper(null);  //this runs fine
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The non-nullable constraint on types is an F# specific feature and so it does not have any representation in .NET (and therefore C# does not respect it).

In fact, you can workaround this even in F# using an unsafe `Unchecked.defaultof<_>` value:

```
let trythis = new Wrapper(Unchecked.defaultof<_>)
```

This is very useful if you want to check for `null` in an object that is exposed to C#:

```
type Wrapper (value: test) =
    if value = Unchecked.defaultof<_> then
      invalidArg "value" "Value should not be null."
    member val Value = value with get, set
```